# How can I configure IIS to host app and not break relative paths?

Tags: iis

I have developed an ASP .Net application (.net framework 4.7).

The app runs without any issues in Visual Studio, and when hosted on Server 2019 (IIS 10)

Now I need to host a different app on the same server. So I created two folders `app1` and `app2` on the main site, then right-clicked each and selected `Convert to Application`. Both were converted and I am now able to point my browser to `http://server/app1` and `http://server/app2` and each application loads.

The only issue is all images, master pages, javascript, css, etc, are all broken since they are being expected to be relative to the main site, and not nested in a sub-path.

What can I do to let IIS resolve all paths in app1 relative to app1 folder, without me having to specify it (hardcode the virtual path)?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue, If am misunderstanding the issue, could share more details about the issue, the minimal reproducible sample is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I follow your description and create 2 brand new projects and can't reproduce the issue. Then I double check the css files and javascript files. It works normally.

Then I think the files can't be loaded should be write by yourself. Could please check it like below, I think the `APP2/Content/css?v=xxxxxx` could be loaded normally.

[image]

#### So my suggestion is

using relative path to load those static files.

Comment: From your screenshots, it appears that you are testing your solution containing multiple projects from your development machine. I know how to configure the IIS on the real server. Can you please tell me how you managed to setup your solution? what configurations did you alter to run both sites from visual studio?

Comment: Hi @Ahmad [The APP1,APP2 and APP3 folders](https://i.imgur.com/4aowWwG.png) contains a standalone .net framework 4.7.2 web application.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I am already using relative path to the static files. But the link ends up being broken. App1 has css definition in its master page. The link must be updated if the page in in the root of App1, and must also be updated for any nested pages (pages inside sub folders of App1) because the relative path ends up pointing to the current level of the requested page

Comment: Hi @Ahmad  Could you create a new sample repo for us, so that we could test it.